# How to extract an item from a list and add it as a column in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, series

I have 3 lists like as shown below

```
numeric_cols = df.select_dtypes(include=np.number).columns # 3 items `qty`, `age`, `sqft`
date_cols = df.select_dtypes(include=['datetime64']).columns # 2 items
string_cols = df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns # 3 items `bucket`, `category`, `level`
```

Now, I would like to

a) select only one item from numeric cols - `qty` and all the items from `string_cols` (so dataframe has to have only 4 columns)

I tried the below

```
df[[*string_cols]] = df[[*string_cols]]
df.insert(2, "Qty",df['Qty'],True)
```

Please note that what I have shown is just a sample. In real data, I have millions of rows and 100's of columns. Hence, I would like to follow the above approach.

Can guide me on how can I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select subset of columns using a list of column names:

```
new_df = df[[*string_cols] + ['Qty']]
```

For example, for DataFrame,

```
Qty  Age  Sqft bucket category level
0   11    8   1.0      a        a     a
1    2    9   0.0      b        b     b
2    3   10   0.0      c        c     c
3   18    3   1.0      d        d     d
4   21    2   NaN      e        e     e
```

```
string_cols = df.select_dtypes(inclue=['object']).columns
new_df = df[[*string_cols] + ['Qty']]
```

produces:

```
  bucket category level  Qty
0      a        a     a   11
1      b        b     b    2
2      c        c     c    3
3      d        d     d   18
4      e        e     e   21
```